# Strip HTML Tags from javascript variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am having the following html :

```
<div id="iView" name="iView" contenteditable="true" style="width: 545px; height:185px; border: 2px solid green;"><p>jgfj</p>hello this</div>
    <input type="button" value="click" onClick="getEditorText();" />
```

And my Script goes here :

```
function getEditorText(){
    var viewContent = document.getElementById('iView').innerHTML;
    alert(viewContent);
    //alert(viewContent.replace(/<([^>]+)>/ig,"")); nothing works
    //alert(viewContent.replace(/(<\S([^>]+)>)/ig,"")); nothing works
    //alert(viewContent.replace(/<[^>]+>/ig,"")); nothing works
    //alert(viewContent.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")); nothing works
    //alert(viewContent.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')); nothing works
}
```

In my first alert it is omitting tags..

But when i include tags dynamically ..it is not omitting the tags..so let me know how to strip the html tags dynamically using javascript , not jquery?

Comment: the out put expected will be a great help please...

Comment: yeah sure vineet.. If we include <p>test</p> inside the div,it should print like as follows :                                   "jgfj

hello this

test"

Answer (score 1):

Modified version of your code that should work properly:

```
function getEditorText() {

    var el = document.getElementById('iView'),
        viewContent = el.innerText || el.textContent;

    viewContent = viewContent.replace(/<([^>]+)>/ig,"")
        .replace(/(<\S([^>]+)>)/ig,"")
        .replace(/<[^>]+>/ig,"")
        .replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")
        .replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');

    el.innerHTML = viewContent;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LRCXM/2/

Note that Firefox needs `textContent` instead of `innerText`.

Comment: it works..good work around dfsq..but when we give wrong tags also its accepting..It should not accept actually..so for that let me know?

Comment: instead of <span>,if we give <sdfdf>test</werwer>...its taking. anything after '<' and '>' considers as html tags

Comment: Of course, because you are telling to your regular expressions to treat it as HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/aKAHEgO/1/)

Comment: No..its not coming..try to add <p>test</p> inside the div and click the button...its printing the same

Comment: @sree I don't think it'd work that way. Because when you type `<` or `>` in the editable area, its inserted as an escape sequence `&lt;` or `&gt;`. you can see this with the first alert.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regular expression to strip the html tags.

```
var strippedString=viewContent.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```